# please let me know what the following lines of code mean

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

What is mean by the following code, I found it in the comment module (drupal 6)

```
return theme('box', $title, drupal_get_form('comment_form', $edit, $title));
```

I have used this theme function before, but I had defined some themes under `hook_theme()`. but I didn't see any themes defined as 'box', also I found same theme 'table'

Could you please show some urls where it explains about these things

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Drupal theme system you can overwrite theme functions. So if you don't like the markup that `theme_box` makes, you can make `my_theme_box` instead and Drupal will use that function instead. The thing is in order for this to work you can't call `theme_box` directly. If you do that you in your module your theme can't alter the output. Instead you call `theme('box', ...)` this will tell Drupal that's it's the box theming function you want. It will the find out which function to call based on what's available. So if your theme doesn't have `my_theme_box` defined `theme_box` will be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already read [Drupal API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/)? There's an explanation about [themes](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/themeable/6), too.

Comment: @John: You need to look for theme_box().  Calling theme('box'...) dispatches calls to the theme_box() "chain" of theming functions.

Comment: Thanks very much, I found that theme('box'...) calling the file box.tpl.php under modules/system folder. but I didnt get from where theme('table'..... comes from, there must be a table.tpl.php I guess. Please let me know if you know this

Comment: Output for table theming is not accomplished via a template file, but through a theming function.  If you want to change the html output by theme_table then you need to create a theme function override.  Copy the contents of theme_table into a function called yourthemename_table and change the bits you want to change.  See this for more info: https://drupal.org/node/341628